# Counting prime ideals and an explicit Landau prime ideal theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem, prime-ideals

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers, and $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$. Let $x\in \mathbb R^+$, and $N(\mathfrak p)$ be the norm of the prime ideal $\mathfrak p$. We consider the sum
$$\sum_{N(\mathfrak p)\leq x}\frac{\log N(\mathfrak p)}{N(\mathfrak p)}\hbox{ and }\sum_{N(\mathfrak p)\leq x}\log N(\mathfrak p).$$
We know 
$$\left|\sum_{N(\mathfrak p)\leq x}\frac{\log N(\mathfrak p)}{N(\mathfrak p)}-\log x\right|\ll_KO(1)$$
and 
$$\left|\sum_{N(\mathfrak p)\leq x}\log N(\mathfrak p)-x\right|\ll_Kx\exp\left(-c_K\sqrt{\log x}\right)$$
for a constant depending on $K$. I would like to know whether there are any explicit estimates of the above issue. Attention, I would like an estimate WITHOUT the assumption of the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, but a worse remainder is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ denote any totally imaginary field. 
Theorem 2 of this paper
(Maciej Grześkowiak
Explicit Bound for the Prime Ideal Theorem in Residue Classes,
(International Conference on Number-Theoretic Methods in Cryptology,
NuTMiC 2017: Number-Theoretic Methods in Cryptology pp 48-68))
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-76620-1_4

contains the estimate for $\left|\sum_{N(p)\leq x}\  \log N(p) -x\right|$
of the type you ask, with explicit constants, (too complicated to state here.) Moreover, it is more general, as it allows residue classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I would like to know whether we could prove it for an arbitrary number field. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Such results follow (after partial summation) from the unconditional effective form of the Chebotarev density theorem due to Lagarias and Odlyzko applied to the trivial Galois extension $K/K$.  Various improvements over their work might be easier to access.  For the sharpest unconditional error terms in the $x$-aspect, see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa52/aa5227.pdf).  For the sharpest unconditional error terms in the $K$-aspect, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02823).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I don't think these two papers are explicit enough, compared with the results assuming GRH.